# How do I automatically cancel Twilio outbound call as soon as the call status changes to ringing

Tags: node.js, twilio

hello there I am using Twilio to place outbound call I have local node app that initiates a call. I also have Twilio status callback function which monitors the status of call. I want to cancel/end the call when the call status changes to "ringing" I have tried to end a call with hangup and reject TwiML. I was expecting a call to be cancelled automatically but my phone keeps ringing.

**node code for placing a call**

```
router.post('/call', async (requ, resp) => {

    const accountSid = myaccoundsid;
    const authToken = myauthtoken;
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
    client.calls
        .create({
            to: 'to_number',
            from: 'from_number',
            url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
            statusCallback: 'url_to_my_status_call_back_function',
            statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
            statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
        })
        .then((call) => {
             console.log(call.status);
        });

   });
```

The call status returned in my terminal is queued.

**My status callback function**

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const response = new VoiceResponse();

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    if(event.CallStatus ==='ringing'){
        console.log("Call status changed: "+ event.CallStatus);
        response.hangup();
        console.log(response.toString());
    }
    callback(null, response);
};
```

**Twilio console**

[image]

any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: I think you can´t cancel a call while is ringing, at least I couldn´t

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First, you should likely check with the Twilio terms, specifically the [terms related to voice calls](https://www.twilio.com/legal/service-country-specific-terms/programmable-voice) to ensure that you do not fall foul of this rule:

> Customer will not have, in a given month, (a) a high volume of unanswered outbound voice call attempts from a single originating phone number or (b) a low average outbound voice call duration. Telecommunications providers may independently block Customer’s use of their networks if Customer engages in any of the foregoing behavior.

If you have a legitimate reason to hang up a call as soon as it starts ringing, then read on.

Status callback webhooks are asynchronous, they happen outside of the call itself, so returning TwiML to them does not affect the call. Instead, to use a status callback to affect a call, you need to [use the REST API to modify the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-resource-to-end-the-call&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) and complete it.

An example of this might be:

```js
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    if(event.CallStatus ==='ringing'){
        const client = context.getTwilioClient();
        await client.calls(event.CallSid).update({ status: 'canceled' });
    }
    callback(null, response);
};
```